# Vim, PHPactor and autocompletion of custom function/class

Tags: php, vim

I use ncm2 with vim + Phpactor.

Here an extract of my vimrc.

```
Plug 'ncm2/ncm2'
Plug 'phpactor/phpactor', { 'do': ':call phpactor#Update()', 'for': 'php'}
Plug 'phpactor/ncm2-phpactor'
Plug 'ncm2/ncm2-ultisnips'
....
inoremap <silent> <expr> <CR> ncm2_ultisnips#expand_or("\<CR>", 'n')
```

All the plug have been installed.

I made some test:

- I can have autocompletion for historical php functon (`substr()` for example)
- I can't have autocompletion for new PHP function `str_contains()` for example
- I have partial autocompletion for my own function.

  - If in the current buffer, it works, but don't show the arguments
  - If in other files of the current project, it does not work at all.

Here just a MWE file.

```
<?php

/**
 * @param string $
 * @return bool
*/
function toto($a) {
    return false;
}
```

`toto` is not autocomplete.

What did I miss in my setup ?

Ps: I am not a professionnal of coding.